# Test the existence of value in different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, left-join

I want to search my column id equal to id1 or id2 then we add column with value of col3 in the F1. else NAN.

```
   d = {'id1': ["ABC","ANB","ATB","BTP"],'id2':["XXX","YYY","ZZZ","TTT"], 'Name': ["A1","A2","A3","A4"]}
   F1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
   d = {'id': ["ABC","ANB","ZZZ"], 'col3': [0,1,1]}
   F2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I did this line of code but it didn"t give the expected result.

```
 pd.concat([F1.merge(F2, left_on='id1', right_on='id'),F1.merge(F2, left_on='id2', right_on='id')], axis=0).drop(['Name','id'], axis=1)
```

The expected output is shown in this figure.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQlst.png)

Comment: Could you share the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for both columns by `Series` created by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace missing values:

```
s = F2.set_index('id')['col3']
F1['col3'] = F1['id1'].map(s).fillna(F1['id2'].map(s))
print (F1)
   id1  id2 Name  col3
0  ABC  XXX   A1   0.0
1  ANB  YYY   A2   1.0
2  ATB  ZZZ   A3   1.0
3  BTP  TTT   A4   NaN
```

**Details**:

```
print (F1['id1'].map(s))
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
Name: id1, dtype: float64

print (F1['id2'].map(s))
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    NaN
Name: id2, dtype: float64

print(F1['id1'].map(s).fillna(F1['id2'].map(s)))
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    NaN
Name: id1, dtype: float64
```

Your solution should be changed with left join and `fillna`:

```
a = F1.merge(F2, left_on='id1', right_on='id', how='left')['col3']
b = F1.merge(F2, left_on='id2', right_on='id', how='left')['col3']

F1['col3'] = a.fillna(b)
print (F1)
   id1  id2 Name  col3
0  ABC  XXX   A1   0.0
1  ANB  YYY   A2   1.0
2  ATB  ZZZ   A3   1.0
3  BTP  TTT   A4   NaN
```

Last if need integers in last column need pandas 0.24+ with casting by [`Int64`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
F1['col3'] = F1['id1'].astype('Int64')
print (F1)
   id1  id2 Name  col3
0  ABC  XXX   A1     0
1  ANB  YYY   A2     1
2  ATB  ZZZ   A3     1
3  BTP  TTT   A4   NaN
```

Comment: thank you it works. can you  explain more what does this line F1['id1'].map(s).fillna(F1['id2'].map(s)) Please

Comment: @Miss - it map column `id1` by series s, if not matched are created mising values. So if use fillna with another mapping are repalced only missing values.

Comment: @Miss - added details to answer for better understanding how it working. Is it OK? Or need explian more?

Comment: what do you mean by  it map column id1 by series s? Thank you

Comment: @Miss - I think lookup by index values, check [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for more explanation.

Comment: THANK YOUU so much